# Are there any dangers of aluminum-containing antiperspirants?

Tags: aluminum

The question was last asked in 2013, and I wondered if there is any more definitive research on this. The german ministry of risks says that there is a possible risk of using them:
https://www.bfr.bund.de/cm/343/aluminiumhaltige-antitranspirantien-tragen-zur-aufnahme-von-aluminium-bei.pdf

However, this is from 2014 and says that there is little definitive data.
Are there any new updates?

Comment: The duplicate was asked in 2016, which isn't long ago in research terms, and post dates your German document. Also: Asking if there are "any dangers" is too broad - there is no way of addressing every possible harm. Please translate a relevant quote from the document that makes a specific claim of a specific harm (e.g. skin cancer?)

Comment: I am confused. That linked paper does go into some detail on everything you are asking about, including sources. Also, the title ("are there any dangers") doesn't match the body ("any new updates?").